# R: Forcing Plotly to Save "Full Sized" Plots?

Tags: html, r, plotly, data-visualization

I am working with the R programming language. I am following the tutorial here :

I was able to make the following plot:

```
library(dplyr)

library(plotly)

data <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/gapminderDataFiveYear.csv")

data_2007 <- data[which(data$year == 2007),]
data_2007 <- data_2007[order(data_2007$continent, data_2007$country),]
slope <- 2.666051223553066e-05
data_2007$size <- sqrt(data_2007$pop * slope)
colors <- c('#4AC6B7', '#1972A4', '#965F8A', '#FF7070', '#C61951')

fig <- plot_ly(data_2007, x = ~gdpPercap, y = ~lifeExp, color = ~continent, size = ~size, colors = colors,
        type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers', sizes = c(min(data_2007$size), max(data_2007$size)),
        marker = list(symbol = 'circle', sizemode = 'diameter',
                      line = list(width = 2, color = '#FFFFFF')),
        text = ~paste('Country:', country, '<br>Life Expectancy:', lifeExp, '<br>GDP:', gdpPercap,
                      '<br>Pop.:', pop))
fig <- fig %>% layout(title = 'Life Expectancy v. Per Capita GDP, 2007',
         xaxis = list(title = 'GDP per capita (2000 dollars)',
                      gridcolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                      range = c(2.003297660701705, 5.191505530708712),
                      type = 'log',
                      zerolinewidth = 1,
                      ticklen = 5,
                      gridwidth = 2),
         yaxis = list(title = 'Life Expectancy (years)',
                      gridcolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                      range = c(36.12621671352166, 91.72921793264332),
                      zerolinewidth = 1,
                      ticklen = 5,
                      gridwith = 2),
         paper_bgcolor = 'rgb(243, 243, 243)',
         plot_bgcolor = 'rgb(243, 243, 243)')
```

Then, I tried saving the file:

```
htmltools::save_html(html = fig, file = "file.html")
```

The problem is, that this plot is saving in a "stretched" format:

[image]

**Is there any way that I can "force" R/plotly to save a "full sized" plot instead of this "stretched" version?**

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want only html output?

Comment: @ Manro: Yes! That is correct!

Answer (score 1):

You could specify the `width` and `height` in `plot_ly` like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

data <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/gapminderDataFiveYear.csv")

data_2007 <- data[which(data$year == 2007),]
data_2007 <- data_2007[order(data_2007$continent, data_2007$country),]
slope <- 2.666051223553066e-05
data_2007$size <- sqrt(data_2007$pop * slope)
colors <- c('#4AC6B7', '#1972A4', '#965F8A', '#FF7070', '#C61951')

fig <- plot_ly(data_2007, x = ~gdpPercap, y = ~lifeExp, color = ~continent, size = ~size, colors = colors,
               type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers', sizes = c(min(data_2007$size), max(data_2007$size)),
               marker = list(symbol = 'circle', sizemode = 'diameter',
                             line = list(width = 2, color = '#FFFFFF')),
               text = ~paste('Country:', country, '<br>Life Expectancy:', lifeExp, '<br>GDP:', gdpPercap,
                             '<br>Pop.:', pop),
               autosize = F, width = 1200, height = 600)
fig <- fig %>% layout(title = 'Life Expectancy v. Per Capita GDP, 2007',
                      xaxis = list(title = 'GDP per capita (2000 dollars)',
                                   gridcolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                                   range = c(2.003297660701705, 5.191505530708712),
                                   type = 'log',
                                   zerolinewidth = 1,
                                   ticklen = 5,
                                   gridwidth = 2),
                      yaxis = list(title = 'Life Expectancy (years)',
                                   gridcolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                                   range = c(36.12621671352166, 91.72921793264332),
                                   zerolinewidth = 1,
                                   ticklen = 5,
                                   gridwith = 2),
                      paper_bgcolor = 'rgb(243, 243, 243)',
                      plot_bgcolor = 'rgb(243, 243, 243)') 

htmltools::save_html(html = fig, file = "file.html")
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Output:

[image]

You can change the size to whatever you want.

Comment: @ Quinten: thank you so much for your answer! Just a question: is there some default option that can be specified such that the output is the "standard size"? Thanks!

Comment: @stats_noob, You could try `autosize = TRUE` in `plot_ly`?